# Why is ARP in Mac going crazy? How to disable it?

Tags: macos, wireshark, arp

This is the first time I am observing the ARP request from my Mac is going crazy. It keeps sending the ARP request for last an hour. The requests are like following (using wireshark)

> 484975    2972.105919000  Apple_XX:XX:XX  Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 172.13.82.204?  Tell 172.13.0.45
>
> 484976    2972.110980000  Apple_XX:XX:XX  Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 172.13.82.205?  Tell 172.13.0.45
>
> 484976    2972.110980000  Apple_XX:XX:XX  Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 172.13.82.205?  Tell 172.13.0.45

What is wrong? How to stop sending ARP request?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong. ARP is a normal part of how ethernet works. It's used to translate IP addresses into MAC addresses, and you can't communicate on an IP network without it.

The only question you should ask is why your machine is trying to talk to 172.13.82.205 and 172.13.82.204. They show up with a reverse IP lookup as "AT&T Internet Services", so it could be something to do with your ISP.